# How to add an event without deleting the existing one, but preventing form submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, events, overriding, handler

I am actually trying to try to add an event to an existing form.

This form is from a Wordpress plugin, so I don't have access to its code.

What I want to do is keep the event of this form, adding an operation (let's say a simple `alert`), and then preventing the default submit effect of the button.

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      [salesforce form="1"] // this is the form generated by the plugin
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var form = document.getElementById("sf_form_salesforce_w2l_lead_1");
</script>
```

So here, I'd like to have the following operations on my form :

- Saleforce effects, which send my form in my saleforce account, which is included in the plugin
- Another function, as we said, a simple `alert();`
- Preventing default effect of forms, meaning no page refresh and no submit, in order to do my own redirect somewhere else

I have no idea if this is possible, but if yes thanks for your help!

Comment: You can attach multiple events to the same element.

Answer (score 1):

You should  be able to attach multiple event Handlers to your form :

```
function originalEventHandler() {
  console.log('Original');
}

function additionalHander() {
  alert('New handler');
}

$('form').on('submit', function(){
  originalEventHandler();
});


$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  additionalHander();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7zbkLvc/)